# Android XML parsing with binary base64 image

Tags: android, xml, web-services

I have an image in a .NET Web Service, where I have `ArrayOfBase64Binary = parent` & `base64Binary = child` tags. I fail to retrieve the XML file in Android. I am using SOAP Web Service for this with `ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.

Can someone help me to retrieve the xml & parse it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get  anyType{} in xml??

Answer (score 0):

`anyType{}` clearly means that you are getting `NULL` value from your SOAP.
May be you should debug the web service and see if it's returning any value there too.
Or try updating your `SOAP Library` to `ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Here is how you can parse the data

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
Log.e("result", result.toString());

SoapObject resultOne = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(0);  //Inside the first tag
SoapObject resultTwo = (SoapObject) resultOne.getProperty(0);  //Inside the second tag

Log.e("Count", resultTwo.getPropertyCount()+"");

for (int i = 0; i < resultTwo.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
        SoapObject resultThree = (SoapObject) resultTwo.getProperty(i);
        Log.e(""+i, resultThree.toString());

        String id = resultThree.getProperty("Id").toString();
        String PartName = resultThree.getProperty("Part_Name").toString();
}
```